# Differentiate between Department and Project group in Gitlab

Tags: github, gitlab

As a `Gitlab` Admin, I have to create different `Groups` for different departments and add members to it. Some Departments conatins Sub-Departments so I create `Sub-Group` in Gitlab for it.

As of now everything ok. But, I came to a situation where, I have create project group so that it can have Software, Hardware and Firware code seperatly stored in it. So, I created a sub-group with Project name and added three individual projects in it.

My question is, Did using `Sub-Group` for both Sub-Department and Sub-Project is ok? Or can I improve this in any way?

PS: I added `Github` tag so that question reaches more people and may have common ideas. Not intended to create any confusion or false tagging.

Answer (score 1):

According to [GitLab's Documentation on Subgroups](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/subgroups/index.html), they are meant specifically for the following reasons:

> - **Separate internal / external organizations.** Since every group can have its own visibility level, you are able to host groups for different purposes under the same umbrella.
> - **Organize large projects.** For large projects, subgroups makes it potentially easier to separate permissions on parts of the source code.
> - **Make it easier to manage people and control visibility.** Give people different permissions depending on their group membership.

So, according to these three reasons provided in the docs, I would say that:

- Yes, Subgroups can definitely be used for Sub-Departments (according to the first and last reason), to create the right departmental / sub-departmental divisions in terms of visibility and and permissions, and
- Yes, Subgroups can definitely be used for Sub-Projects of a bigger Project (according to the second reason), to separate permissions on parts of the source code to organize large Projects.

In order to provide a differentiation between Groups / Subgroups there are two main tools available in GitLab:

- **Group / Subgroup name.** You may specify a specific prefix or infix to differentiate project groups / subgroups from departmental ones. For instance `sp-`, having `project1-sp-firmware` for the Subproject firmware subgroup and `project1-marketing` for the marketing Subdepartment. (This is just an example to give an idea, you should of course look at the best solution for your own specific organization and structure.)
- **Avatars**. You may specify different kinds of avatars (specific colors or subjects) according if it is a Subdepartment or a Subproject. For instance, blue avatars for Subprojects and yellow avatars for Subdepartments. Or same color within the same department... and so on. Here is a website that generates letters avatars (max 2 letters): https://ui-avatars.com.